# How to show a countdown timer in react

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I am using moment.js.
I want to show a count down timer if an event is delayed.
I am getting the eventStartDate from the BE but I am not sure how to show timer with respect to current time.

So far I have tried like this

```
const currentDateAndTime = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
const eventStartDateAndTime = moment.tz(moment(eventStartDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'), timeZone).local();
```

I want to show the countdown timer here
https://prnt.sc/kXqBjQOFab6m
Can you please help me with the logic?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you will get the idea from this. Read about 'useEffect' and cleanup.

```
function Timer() {
  const [state,setState] = useState(0);

  useEffect(()=> {
    // Increase state with every 1 second
    const interval = setInterval(()=> setState(prevState => prevState + 1),1000)
    // Clean up interval
    return ()=> interval;
  },[])

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{state}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```